# Deserialize json in python to a separate value

Tags: python, json, serialization

I have a Arduino that publish a json string in MQTT server.
I read the topic with python and see this:

```
{"temp1": 123, "vol1": 456, "cur1": 789, "pf1": 321, "p1":654}
```

How can I divide the various parts and assign them to a variable to be used later in the script?

es:

```
temp1 = 123
vol1 = 456
```

edit:
my json string is like this: `{"temp1":26.44,"vol1":0.00,"cur1":0.04,"pf1":1.00,"p1":4000.00,"s1":0.00,"f1":48.84,"p1max":4000.00,"en1":16.00,"prev_en1":0.00,"m_en1":0.00,"prev_m_en1":0.00}`

```
    pacdata = msg.payload.decode("utf-8")
    print("pacdata= ",str(pacdata))
    my_set = str(pacdata)
    print("my_set= ",my_set)
    my_var = []
    my_var1 = []
    for x,y in my_set.items():
        print (x,'=',y)
        x = y
    print("value temp1: ", my_set['temp1'])
```

If I write (copy) this string with your code all works fine, if I use the variable that contains this string the script don't work...
Why?

Thanks!

Comment: why assign them to variables you can access from dictionary

Comment: After I use this variables to print in a display. I don't know how use the dictionary,

Comment: where you stuck now? did you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried various ways looking on the web but I cannot find the correct way. Maybe I'm not looking properly because I just can't find anything that is right for me

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to achieve and what exactly your problem is. Assigning to variables and working with dictionaries are very basic operations of Python. Consider to do a [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) if you are unsure about the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really do not need to divide a dictionary into various parts to keep each as variable to use later. A dictionary exist for the purpose usually, that keys can be used as your variables and the values as such whenever you need to. You only need to iterate through the dictionary this way to get want you want whenever:

```
my_set = {"temp1": 123, "vol1": 456, "cur1": 789, "pf1": 321, "p1":654}
for x,y in my_set.items():
   print (x,'=',y)
```

As you'll notice, the keys can be declared as variables and the values assigned to them

Comment: This assigns the values to the *name ``x``*, not to the "names" ``temp1``, ``vol1``, ... initially stored in ``x``.

Comment: OK thank you very much!
I've tried and it's already a great step forward.
If I wanted to print a specific variable, how could I do?
For example print only "pf1"

Comment: just write `my_set['p1'] and you'll get `654` printed

Comment: @MisterMiyagi - Thanks for the observation, i've corrected it

Comment: oh my it was really simple but I would never have gotten there alone!
Thanks so much! +1

Comment: `my_set = str(pacdata)` what do you want to achieve with this statement?

Comment: if what you are trying to do is convert a json string to dictionary, you may just do this: `import json` `my_set=json.loads(pacdata)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220565/discussion-between-seyi-daniel-and-agarest).

Comment: Sorry, I have a little problem with this code. If in the JSON one or more value are text (not numeric value) the de-serialization crashes